# Remove multiple rows if data is null in either of 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a dataset in which each row consists of the columns: year, college name, number of undergrad students, and number of grad students.

For each college name, there are 4 rows of data (the years 2013-2016).  If there is missing data for EITHER the number of undergrad students or the number of grad students for any of the 4 years, I want to delete ALL 4 rows for that college.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: A reasonably straight forward macro.  Assuming the data is sorted into college then year, run through the data looking for blanks, when you find one delete the four rows.  You'll calculate where the block of four rows starts by using the year field.

Comment: I'm very new at VBA, could you show me what this might look like? And yes, the data is sorted by college and then year.

Comment: I guess it might be possible but certainly quite difficult to copy blocks of 4 rows across to another sheet by formula where there are no missing student numbers. A fairly ugly Offset formula I think.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  Assumes that the year field is a number rather than text.

```
Sub DeleteColleges()
    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("a2")

    Do While Not rg = ""
        If rg.Offset(0, 2) = "" Or rg.Offset(0, 3) = "" Then
            yearRow = rg.Value - 2012   'see note 1
            Set rg = rg.Offset(5 - yearRow, 0)  'see note 2
            rg.Offset(-4, 0).Range("a1:a4").EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note 1: this calculates what year row we are in, from row 1 for 2013 to row 4 for 2016

Note 2: the range ('rg') is moved into the next college before we delete the rows, otherwise rg will become null when we delete the rows and the macro will fail

Note 3: the code needs to be more robust then this.  As a minimum I would ensure that the number of data rows is a multiple of four (anything else would indicate a problem with the data), and that column A only contains the four values 2013 to 2016.

It might also be worth changing the code to look for non-numbers rather than just blanks cells

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it is possible by formula but hard work

```
=IFERROR(IF(MOD(ROW(),4)=2,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET($C$2,(ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1)*4,0,4,2))=8)*
(COUNTIF($I$1:$I1,INDEX($B:$B,N(IF({1},(ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1)*4+2))))=0),0)*4-2),
INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I1,$B:$B,0)+MOD(ROW()-2,4))),"")
```

The first two lines of the formula relate to line 1 of the block of 4 records and the third line relates to lines 2-4.

The first line of the formula uses Offset and Subtotal to check 4 X 2 blocks of student numbers to see if the count is 8. The Match picks up the first college which has complete data and hasn't been previously listed.

The second line uses an Index construct to get a list of the different college names and checks if they have already been listed using Countif. ROW($A$1:$A$10) would need changing to deal with more than 10 colleges.

The third line of the formula finds the matching college record using the name in the row above the current row and picks up the data from the appropriate row and column in the original data.

[image]

Assumes that everything starts in row 2.